# Error in the PSTricks package pst-poly?

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\sidelaengde{5 }
\def\myCoor{}
\centering
 \psset{unit = 0.4}
  \begin{pspicture}(-12.5,-13.1)(12.5,10.6)
   \psset{
     linewidth = 1pt,
     linecolor = green!90!yellow!70!blue!70,
     fillstyle = solid,
     fillcolor = green!60!yellow!80!blue!80
   }
    \rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[unit = \sidelaengde]}
    \pstVerb{/R1 \sidelaengde 36 cos mul dup add def /R2 R1 \sidelaengde add def}
    \multido{\iA = -90+72}{5}{%
      \xdef\myCoor{\myCoor(!R2 \iA\space PtoC)}
      \rput{36}(!R1 \iA\space PtoC){\PstPentagon[unit = \sidelaengde]}}
    \rput(!1.55 \sidelaengde mul neg 0.2 \sidelaengde mul){\sidelaengde cm}
   \psset{
     fillstyle = none,
     linewidth = 1pt,
     linecolor = black
   }
    \expandafter
    \pspolygon
    \myCoor
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

As can be seen, the black pentagon doesn't surround the smaller, green pentagons perfectly. In the past, the 'fit' has been perfect so I wonder if an error has been introduced into [`pst-poly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly) at some point.

**Update**

I also have the problem with the following PSTricks figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-poly,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\sider{6}
\def\radius{3.5}
\pstFPdiv\vinkel{360}{\sider}
\centering
 \psset{
   unit = 0.9,
   linejoin = 2
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
    \pscircle(0,0){\radius}
    \rput(0,0){\PstPolygon[ PolyNbSides = \sider, unit = \radius]}
    \multido{\r = 0+\vinkel}{\sider}{%
      \psRelLine[angle = \r, linestyle = dotted](0,0)(\radius,0){1}{A}}
    \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = 9pt](0,0)(\radius,0)
    \ncput{$r = \radius\,\text{cm}$}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

**Update 2**

Here is the output from `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
pst-poly.sty    2009/12/20 package wrapper for pst-poly.tex (dg,hv)
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/07/31 v2.56 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/07/31 v2.56 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   dvips.def    2014/04/23 v3.0j Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pst-poly.tex    2009/12/20 v1.61 `PST-poly' (dg,hv)
pstricks-add.sty    2010/02/11 v. 0.14 package wrapper for pstricks-add.tex (hv)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
pst-plot.tex    2014/08/23 1.70 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pst-node.tex    2014/08/23 1.70 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
  pst-3d.sty    2009/07/28 package wrapper for pst-3d.tex (hv)
  pst-3d.tex    2010/02/14 v1.11 `PST-3d' (hv)
pst-math.sty    2014/07/30 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-math.tex
pstricks-add.tex    2014/07/22 v3.75 `PSTricks-add' (hv)
pstricks-add.cfg    2005/01/10 v0.1 addtional user stuff (hv)
```

Comment: Both your examples work fine for me using MiKTeX (updated today).

Comment: @Christoph Hmmm. That's wired! I use TeX Live 2014, updated today, on a Linux machine. Do you (or anyone else) have an idea of what's wrong?

Comment: I can check only this evening on my Linux box with TeXLive 2014. You could add a `\listfiles` to see if any PSTricks from a local texmf-tree is used instead of the TeXLive version.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you for taking the time to check later. I've updated my question with the list of files.

Comment: Ok, here with MikTeX I have `pstricks.tex` version 2.49b (dated 2013/12/21). Using 2.56 I can reproduce your problem, although I don't yet know where the error exactly is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is a bug with a trailing space in `\PstPolygon`. Try the version from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-poly/  It should fix it, as can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: I assume it gets on CTAN as soon as possible, right? `:)`

Comment: sure, should be available at least tomorrow.