# Error in PSTricks package -- trailing space again?

Tags: pstricks

This question is similar to [Error in the PSTricks package pst-poly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198263/error-in-the-pstricks-package-pst-poly/).

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-grad,pstricks-add}

\newcommand*\PolyLine{%
  \psarc(C){\RelRadiusB}{!90 \vinkelA add}{180}
  \psline(B)(A)(D)
  \psarc(C){\RelRadiusB}{0}{!90 \vinkelA sub}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\radius{21.65}
\def\vinkelA{12 }
\def\vinkelB{71 }
\pstFPdiv\faktor{1}{3}
\pstFPmul\RelFaktor{2}{\faktor}
\pstFPmul\rammeA{\radius}{\faktor}
\pstFPadd\rammeB{\rammeA}{2.95}
\makeatletter
  \pst@getsinandcos{\vinkelA}
  \pstFPmul\RelRadiusB\faktor{\radius}
  \pstFPmul\MaxLW\RelRadiusB\pst@sin
  \pstFPmul\MaxLW{2}{\MaxLW}
 \psset{unit = 0.5}
  \begin{pspicture}(-\rammeA,-\rammeA)(\rammeA,\rammeB)
    \pst@getsinandcos{\vinkelB}
      \ifnum \vinkelB = 90
       \let \RelLW\MaxLW
      \else
      \ifnum \vinkelB > 90
        \pstFPmul\RelLW{\MaxLW}{\pst@cos}
      \else
        \pstFPmul\RelLW{\MaxLW}{\pst@sin}
      \fi
    \fi
    \pnodes%
      (-\RelRadiusB,-\RelRadiusB){A}%
      (-\RelRadiusB,0){B}%
      (0,0){C}%
      (\RelRadiusB,-\RelRadiusB){D}%
      (!0 \RelRadiusB\space \vinkelA cos mul){T1}
    \pscustom[
      linewidth = 2pt,
      linecolor = red,
      fillstyle = gradient,
      gradbegin = blue!5,
      gradmidpoint = 1,
      gradend = blue!35
    ]{\PolyLine}
    \begin{psclip}{%
      \pscustom[linestyle = none]{
        \PolyLine
        \psline(\RelRadiusB,\RelRadiusB)(!\RelRadiusB\space dup 3 add)%
               (!\RelRadiusB\space dup neg exch 3 add)(-\RelRadiusB,\RelRadiusB)}}
      \rput(!0 \RelRadiusB\space \vinkelA cos mul){%
        \pcline[linecolor = yellow, linewidth = \RelLW, nodesep = -\radius]%
          (0,0)(!\vinkelB dup 90 ne {-1 exch neg Tan neg} {0 -1} ifelse)}
    \end{psclip}
    \pscustom[linewidth = 2pt, linecolor = black!70]{\PolyLine}
    \psline[linestyle = dotted]({-\RelRadiusB,0}|T1)({\RelRadiusB,0}|T1)
    \rput(!\RelRadiusB\space 90 \vinkelA sub PtoC){%
      \pswedge(0,0){1}{!180 \vinkelB sub}{180}
      \uput{1}[!180 \vinkelB 2 div sub](0,0){\footnotesize $\vinkelB^{\ensuremath{\circ}}$}
      \psline[linestyle = dotted](0,0)(!3 180 \vinkelB sub PtoC)}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the sunbeam doesn't go perfectly through hole in the roof, as it has in the past, but it's shifted slightly to the right. Is this also do to a trailing space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use:

```
\pscustom[
  linewidth = 2pt,
  linecolor = red,
  fillstyle = gradient,
  gradbegin = blue!5,
  gradmidpoint = 1,
  gradend = blue!35
]{\PolyLine}%  <<=======
```

`\pscustom` has no `\ignorespaces` at the end and together with the following `\psclip`, which has no `\pst@killglue` at the beginning, the above space is not "eaten" by PSTricks.